# Failed to load the TSLint library for the document in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, tslint, tsc

I have installed the latest versions of Visual Studio Code, Node.js, and Typescript on my Windows 10 machine. However, when I try to use TSLint in the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to load the TSLint library for the document...
```

I tried reinstalling TSLint, but I got the following error message:

```
npm install -g tslint
```

And got the following message:

```
npm WARN tslint@5.11.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@2.29.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ tslint@5.11.0
updated 1 package in 1.853s
```

Restarting Visual Studio Code did not help, and I am still getting the error message that TSLint cannot be loaded.

- TSC 3.2.2
- VSC 1.29.1

How can I fix this issue and use TSLint in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Where does the error appear? In the terminal or in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

`tsutils` and `typescript` are "peer" dependencies of TSLint, meaning TSLint requires that they be installed but won't do it for you _(this helps make sure TSLint uses the dependency versions you have, rather than providing confusingly different versions on its own). Try:

npm i tsutils typescript

...to install them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that error message informing you about the missing extension? It bundles its own version of TSLint.

Try installing the [vscode-tslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) extension.